# iOS Sorting with bubble sort but last row not sorted

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, ios4, loops

I've completed sorting dates with bubble sort. However, halfway through testing I've noticed that it does not sort the last row. Can anyone help? :( it's very important to me as it's the basis of what I need to do my codes for the sorting:

```
NSInteger count = [sortingArray count];
        for(int a = 0 ; a < count; a++) {
            for(int b = a+1 ; b < count; b++) {
            NSDictionary *dic = [items objectAtIndex:a];
            NSDictionary *dic2 = [items objectAtIndex:b];
            NSString *dateString = [dic valueForKey:@"date"];
            NSString *dateString2 = [dic2 valueForKey:@"date"];
            //NSLog(@"DATE: %@", dateString);   //date is the string representation.

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
            NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
            NSDate *endDate2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString2];

            NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
            NSString *startDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
            NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDateString];
            [dateFormatter release];

            NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
            NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorianCalendar components: NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                                          fromDate:startDate 
                                                            toDate:endDate
                                                           options:0];


            NSDateComponents *comp2 = [gregorianCalendar components: NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                                           fromDate:startDate
                                                             toDate:endDate2
                                                            options:0];
            [gregorianCalendar release];

            NSInteger compareDay = [comp day];    
            NSInteger compareDay2 = [comp2 day];  
            NSString *dayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", compareDay];
                NSString *dayString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", compareDay2];
            NSLog(@"string 1%@", dayString); 
                NSLog(@"string 2 ----%@", dayString2); 

            if (compareDay > compareDay2){
                [sortingArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:a withObjectAtIndex:b];
            } 
        }    //b loop
    }   //a loop
        NSInteger counterIndex = [sortingArray count];
        for(int c = 0; c < counterIndex ; c++) {
            [temp addObject:[sortingArray objectAtIndex:c]];
        }
```

[how it looks like for now](https://995752eb-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/1004606hmp/photo.jpeg?attachauth=ANoY7crIQ0EBA0sI3EiZmO-2qizMwsm8PGPJ9zEhcb094lJAn0-zSgRzXDNJfNE06wSo-bN-qw11_rd-xZbv7tKzXnRT_tmCjg2-o1gqEJKYO3e5n2R0wGIfYhFNF7JCP5TvIunYNzu5NEkexgOnVrL5L8TmO1ECzbt23zKTelJmKRlzARLgBz9I1_pI2_niHKIzj8GySbNrFabD4_pt0I5L-wM-Rs6VXg==&attredirects=0) Please help many many manyyyyy thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your initial for loops like this:

```
    for(int a = 0 ; a < count-1; a++) { // Allow uptil second last position in array
        for(int b = a+1 ; b < count; b++) {  // Allow uptil last position in array
```

I guess this is what missed out.
Try this out. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: oh gosh it worked right away! I was figuring for so long and it was that. Thanks so much!

Comment: m trying my best to help for iOS, objective-c, oops, c, c++ technologies. m happy that it helps you. :)

Comment: sorry I need help again! after adding the count-1 it worked fine ytd but today as i added in another value, the last row was not sorted again! any idea why?:( stuck again!!

Comment: No it should work, there might be some other issue. Try with just 2 values in array and then eventually add data the array.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used the NSSortDescriptor to sort anyway. Initially i used it but at the display nothing comes out therefore I created my own large chunk of codes to do my date sorting. Anyway the method I used:

```
NSLog(@"Before sorting: %@", temp);  // What I have is a NSMutableArray called temp
    NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"date" ascending: YES];

    NSArray *sortedArray = [temp sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: dateSortDescriptor]];
    NSLog(@"After Sorting: %@", sortedArray);        
    NSMutableArray *afterSorting = [[(NSArray*)sortedArray mutableCopy]autorelease];
```

What I did was just to convert the NSArray back to NSMutableArray before I insert it into my tables :) Hope this might help other people and thanks to people that helped me^^